# Browse files backed up with duplicity?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, backup, duplicity

I backed up a long time ago (have been traveling for a few months and moving) with duplicity. My ubuntu installation broke, so I 'fixed' it by having it overwrite my Windows partition, even though I selected to install it side-by-side Windows.

Nonetheless, the critical files from windows that I need are backed up to my external drive. Now that I have access, how can I restore the `My Documents` folder from my duplicity backup without remembering the exact folder structure to get there? Is there a way to 'see' what the directories that are backed up?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Duplicity has options to

1. List backup sets `duplicity collection-status`
2. List files inside a backup set `duplicity list-current-files`

As an example, you can know which backup sets are available :

```
duplicity collection-status /location/of/your/backups
```

And then list files of the 5 months ago backup set :

```
duplicity list-current-files -t 5M /location/of/your/backups | less
```

Finally you can restore with :

```
duplicity -t 5M --file-to-restore "path/to/My Documents" /location/of/your/backups /home/user/where_to_restore
```

Hope this can help, even if the question was asked long time ago...

Answer (score 3):

see https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/Help/Restore/WorstCase
follow instructions under Restoring by Hand 
but instead of tar xf use tar tvf 
this is going to list the contents of the archive instead of extracting it